# D3 General update pattern transition not working on pie chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I have a project where I am using a Pie/Doughnut chart to visualize my data. I have added the general update pattern in order to create a smooth transition when my data changes/updates.

In order to accomplish this I have followed an example which uses the general update pattern on a pie chart: [Bl.ocks example](https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/e1acaf628b1693f1b32e5f2e1a7f73fb).

The problem I am facing is that the chart doesn't update smoothly when updating the data. The chart instantly swaps from one state into the next.

In this and other examples they define a `arcTween` method where d3 interpolates between the previous angles and the angles from the newly updated data:

```
    arcTween(a) {
      let i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    }
```

I also have added the code where I join, enter and update my data to the pie chart. Here I first create the group element where the pie is being drawn in. I also define a transition using the 'arcTween' method to transition between the states. And lastly I also define the 'this._current' when the pie is created:

```
      this.g = this.svg
        .selectAll("doughnut")
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

      this.g
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween);

      this.g
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d => {
          return this.arc(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(d => {
          this._current = d;
        });
```

This is my full code. This is being written in Vue.js. I have tried to get this to work inside a snippet. But I couldn't get it to work.

The images that are shown on top of the doughnut slices are locally stored:

```
<template>
  <div class="p-5 flex flex-col h-full">
    <h2 class="mb-3">{{ title }}</h2>
    <div ref="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-7 m-7">
      <div v-for="item in data" :key="item.key" class="flex">
        <img
          :src="require('@/assets/img/doughnut/' + item.icon)"
          alt=""
          class="doughnutIcon mr-4"
        />
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <h3>{{ item.key }}</h3>
          <p class="opacity-50">
            {{ formatNumberValue(item.value) }} {{ unit }}
          </p>
          <p class="opacity-50">{{ percentageOfTotal(item.value) }} %</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { converter } from "@/shared";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "DoughnutChartItem",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    unit: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmount: 0,
      svg: undefined,
      arc: undefined,
      radius: undefined,
      g: undefined
    };
  },
  created() {
    let total = 0;
    this.data.forEach(item => {
      total += item.value;
    });
    this.totalAmount = total;
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = 1;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    this.svg = d3
      .select(this.$refs.my_dataviz)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
      );

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    this.pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

    // declare an arc generator function
    this.arc = d3
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(100)
      .innerRadius(50);

    this.setSlicesOnDoughnut(this.data);

    this.addImagesToSlices();
  },
  methods: {
    animateSliceOnHover(radius, path, dir) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 0:
          path
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .ease(d3.easeBounce)
            .attr(
              "d",
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(100)
                .outerRadius(50)
            );
          path.style("fill", "#206BF3");
          break;

        case 1:
          path.transition().attr(
            "d",
            d3
              .arc()
              .innerRadius(50)
              .outerRadius(110)
          );
          path.style("fill", "white");
          break;
      }
    },
    percentageOfTotal(amount) {
      return Math.round((amount / this.totalAmount) * 100);
    },
    formatNumberValue(amount) {
      return converter.formatNumberValue(amount);
    },
    setSlicesOnDoughnut(data) {
      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      var data_ready = this.pie(
        data.map(function(d) {
          return [d["key"], d["value"], d["icon"], d["hover"]];
        })
      );

      this.g = this.svg
        .selectAll("doughnut")
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

      this.g
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween);

      this.g
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d => {
          return this.arc(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(d => {
          this._current = d;
        });

      // Add tooltip
      d3.selectAll(".slice")
        .on("mouseover", this.mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", this.mousemove)
        .on("mouseout", this.mouseout);
    },
    addImagesToSlices() {
      var image_width = 20;
      var image_height = 20;

      this.g.selectAll(".logo").remove();

      this.g
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("transform", d => {
          var x = this.arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width / 2;
          var y = this.arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height / 2;
          return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        })
        .attr("class", "logo")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return `${d.data[0]}-logo`;
        })
        .attr("href", function(d) {
          return require("@/assets/img/doughnut/" + d.data[2]);
        })
        .attr("width", image_width)
        .attr("height", image_height);
    },
    mouseover(event, data) {
      //Swap doughnut icon to blue icon
      d3.selectAll("." + data.data[0] + "-logo").attr("href", d => {
        return require("@/assets/img/doughnut/" + d.data[3]);
      });

      this.animateSliceOnHover(this.radius, d3.select(event.currentTarget), 1);

      const tip = d3.select(".tooltip");

      tip
        .style("left", `${event.clientX + 15}px`)
        .style("top", `${event.clientY}px`)
        .transition()
        .style("opacity", 0.98);

      tip.select("h3").html(`${data.data[0]}`);
      tip
        .select("h4")
        .html(`${this.formatNumberValue(data.data[1])} ${this.unit}`);
    },
    mousemove(event) {
      // Move tooltip
      d3.select(".tooltip")
        .style("left", `${event.clientX + 15}px`)
        .style("top", `${event.clientY}px`);
    },
    mouseout(event, data) {
      //Swap doughnut icon to white icon
      d3.selectAll("." + data.data[0] + "-logo").attr("href", function(d) {
        return require("@/assets/img/doughnut/" + d.data[2]);
      });

      // Animate slice
      var thisPath = d3.select(event.currentTarget);
      this.animateSliceOnHover(this.radius, thisPath, 0);

      // if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {
      //   this.animateSliceOnHover(this.radius, thisPath, 0);
      // }

      // Hide tooltip
      d3.select(".tooltip")
        .transition()
        .style("opacity", 0);
    },
    arcTween(a) {
      let i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    }
  },
  watch: {
    data() {
      this.setSlicesOnDoughnut(this.data);

      this.addImagesToSlices();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have shortened the code and included into a code snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      data: [
        [
          {
            key: "one",
            value: 123
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 232
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 186
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            key: "one",
            value: 145
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 270
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 159
          }
        ],
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = 1;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;
    this.width = 250;
    this.height = 250;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    this.svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
      );

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    this.pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

    // declare an arc generator function
    this.arc = d3
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(100)
      .innerRadius(50);

    this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();

  },methods: {
    swapData() {
      if(this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
      else this.index = 0;
      this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();
    },
    setSlicesOnDoughnut() {
      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      var data_ready = this.pie(
        this.data[this.index].map(function(d) {
          return [d["key"], d["value"]];
        })
      );
      
      console.log(data_ready);

      // join
      var arcs = this.svg.selectAll(".arc").data(data_ready);

      // update
      arcs
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween);

      // enter
      arcs
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("d", this.arc)
        .each((d, i, n) => {
          n[i]._current = d;
        });
    }
  },
    arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="swapData">Swap</button>
  <div id="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

The snippet that works, but the slices change position:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      data: [
        [{
            key: "one",
            value: 123
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 232
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 186
          },
          {
            key: "four",
            value: 238
          }
        ],
        [{
            key: "one",
            value: 145
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 270
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 159
          },
          {
            key: "four",
            value: 168
          }
        ],
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = 1;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;
    this.width = 250;
    this.height = 250;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    this.svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
      );

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    this.pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

    // declare an arc generator function
    this.arc = d3
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(100)
      .innerRadius(50);

    this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();

  },
  methods: {
    swapData() {
      if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
      else this.index = 0;
      this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();
    },
    arcTween(a, j, n) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(n[j]._current, a);
      n[j]._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    },
    setSlicesOnDoughnut() {
      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      var data_ready = this.pie(
        this.data[this.index].map(function(d) {
          return [d["key"], d["value"]];
        })
      );

      //console.log(data_ready);

      // join
      var arcs = this.svg.selectAll(".arc").data(data_ready);

      // update
      arcs
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween);

      // enter
      arcs
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("d", this.arc)
        .each((d, i, n) => {
          n[i]._current = d;
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="swapData">Swap</button>
  <div id="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your setSlicesOnDoughnut method, have you tried chaining all your functions after this.g? So don't break them up into this.g groups but just chain them altogether.

Comment: @rguttersohn Thanks for your answer! I don't really seem to get what you mean with chaining them altogether? I think you a referring to the  `.enter().append("g")` part where I add a group element to each of the slices?

Comment: The method would look like this:  

this.g = this.svg
        .selectAll("doughnut")
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween)
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d => {
          return this.arc(d)
        })
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(d => {
          this._current = d;
        });

Comment: @rguttersohn When i try your code i get the following error: `hook: "TypeError: this.svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...).transition(...).duration(...).attrTween(...).append is not a function"` I also don't see why this would fix the problem? I mean it does simplify the code but it does not solve the main problem I am facing.

Comment: I read that your pie is not transitioning smoothly. Instead, it's just updating. I've had this happen before when breaking up the d3 "chain" especially when animating after a click event or when using intersection observer. Basically, d3 can sometimes lose its data binding when the chain is broken. I think that's what is happening here, but I can't tell where yet. Let me know if I misread the issue you are having.

Comment: Bear with me one more time. Try this:  this.g
        .append("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween)
        .attr("d", d => {
          return this.arc(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(d => {
          this._current = d;
        });
Here you are adding path, then adding your transition functions, and then adding in your data.

Comment: @rguttersohn I have updated my code to:    
   this.g = this.svg
        .selectAll("doughnut")
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

      this.g
        .append("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween)
        .attr("d", d => {
          return this.arc(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .each(d => {
          this._current = d;
        });

Comment: @rguttersohn But it still instantly updates the doughnut chart without any form of animation.

Comment: Try commenting out your .attrTween function for now and see if the doughnut chart at least transitions when that function is removed.

Comment: @rguttersohn It still instantly jumps from one data state to the next.

Comment: That's a **lot** of code! I remember turning away from this question when it was first posted because of the sheer amount of code. That makes the core of the problem needlessly inaccessible for anyone willing to help. Please, try to boil it down to the bare minimum. You can easily ditch all styling—be it stylesheet or method calls—, the entire event handling, all Vue-related stuff and reduce it to the minimal code required to demonstrate the issue; in other words, please set up a [mcve].This should be feasible in a Stack Snippet as well.

Comment: @altocumulus I have included the parts that contain the main problem in the first two code blocks. These both contain the main code to make the transition work properly. The big block of code at the bottom represents the full component of the d3 in case the I have overseen something in a part that isn't directly connected to the main problem.

Comment: @Stephen I am still mostly guessing because—as I have mentioned earlier—I find this inaccessible but to me the usage of `this._current` looks suspicious. Especially the setting of the value: `.each(d => { this._current = d; });`. This is going to store only the last d of the `.each()` loop in the variable. That's most likely not what you want. I can only repeat myself: setting up a [mcve] will be of great help tackling the issue. Even the process of setting it up might be enough to unmask the real nature of the problem.

Comment: I second what @altocumulus said. So, just guessing, it seems to me that you have a confusion regarding the meaning of `this`... it seems to me that inside the `each` the `this` should be the DOM element. In that case, try `.each((d, i, n) => {n[i]._current = d;});` in the last line of your second code block.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado @ altocumulus I have tried the solution in adding the `.each((d, i, n) => {n[i]._current = d;});` but it did not fix my problem. I have created a code snippet with the bare code of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two changes made your snippet work.

The first one was moving the `arcTween` method up in the `methods` object. Since I'm not a Vue user and as this makes no sense from a JS perspective (the object's properties order shouldn't matter), I'll leave that part for you to investigate.

The second change is just related to the meaning of `this`. You're mixing `this` as the `method` object (as in `this.arc`) and `this` as the DOM element (as in `this._current`). Like I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916993/d3-general-update-pattern-transition-not-working-on-pie-chart/66002854#comment116666076_65916993), just use the third and second arguments combined to refer to the DOM element (in the vast majority of D3 methods).

That said, this...

```
arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    }
```

...should be:

```
arcTween(a, j, n) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(n[j]._current, a);
  n[j]._current = i(0);
  return t => {
    return this.arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Here is your snippet with those two changes:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      data: [
        [{
            key: "one",
            value: 123
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 232
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 186
          }
        ],
        [{
            key: "one",
            value: 145
          },
          {
            key: "two",
            value: 270
          },
          {
            key: "three",
            value: 159
          }
        ],
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = 1;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;
    this.width = 250;
    this.height = 250;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    this.svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
      );

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    this.pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

    // declare an arc generator function
    this.arc = d3
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(100)
      .innerRadius(50);

    this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();

  },
  methods: {
    swapData() {
      if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
      else this.index = 0;
      this.setSlicesOnDoughnut();
    },
    arcTween(a, j, n) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(n[j]._current, a);
      n[j]._current = i(0);
      return t => {
        return this.arc(i(t));
      };
    },
    setSlicesOnDoughnut() {
      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      var data_ready = this.pie(
        this.data[this.index].map(function(d) {
          return [d["key"], d["value"]];
        })
      );

      //console.log(data_ready);

      // join
      var arcs = this.svg.selectAll(".arc").data(data_ready);

      // update
      arcs
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", this.arcTween);

      // enter
      arcs
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("d", this.arc)
        .each((d, i, n) => {
          n[i]._current = d;
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="swapData">Swap</button>
  <div id="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got it to work in my code. But I have still a problem with it. When I add a fourth variable to the data `four: 238` & `four: 168`. Then the slices change position when they are updated? I have included a snipper of your working example and the fourth variable into the question.

Comment: Not sure about positioning the `arcTween()` method. As you mentioned yourself this doesn't make sense from a JS point of view. Works for me even in the last position of that object: https://jsfiddle.net/xsj23emw/

Comment: @altocumulus it's a mystery indeed: if you copy my snippet (*"copy snippet to answer"*) and move `arcTween` down, you'll see it won't work (I'm using Chrome on Mac).

Comment: @Stephen to be completely honest I stopped reading your comment when I got to *"But I have still a problem with it"*. If you have an additional, different issue, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's what I did in the first place before creating the fiddle. It works for me either way in Chrome, FF, Edge... on Windows, though. Not inclinded to fire up my Mac.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It works in your example. But when I add a fourth variable to the data `four: 238` & `four: 168`. Then the slices change position when they are updated? I mean why does it work with 3 variables but not with 4?

Answer (score 0):

the code really works, you can see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1Lk8zqud/1/

If you really need to have the containers, then you need to have some considerations:

1. You need to consider the containers with the full d3 update pattern:
2. New containers -> set the attr d, append a path, append an image
   3 - Existing containers -> no appends, just update the path and image
   4 - remove the containers not needed

In case of new containers, remember that they are added with the final path (no transitions), so its better to lower the old containers in order to dont mess up with the transitions. I didn't try it with images.

So here is the new version

````
const g = svg.selectAll('g.arcs')
    .data(data_ready, function(d) { return d.index; });

//  new data -> add arcs
    g.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'arcs')
      .lower()
      .append('path')
        .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("stroke", "#2D3546")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", function(a) {
            let i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
                return this.arc(i(t));
            };
       });
       
// old data -> transition data on the container g (for using with the images). Don't add arcs
   g.raise()
       .transition()
       .duration(1500)
       .attrTween("d", function(a) {
            let i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
                return this.arc(i(t));
            };
       });
       
       // transition the path inside the old containers g
       g.select('path').transition()
       .duration(1500)
       .attrTween("d", function(a) {
            let i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
                return this.arc(i(t));
            };
       })

  g.exit().lower().transition().duration(1500).remove();```


A working version of this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rtLbyn52/
````

Comment: Hi Carlos, I first of all thanks for your detailed answer. I have tried to implement your code. You are correct in saying that I create new "g" elements on each new render of data. But I use these "g" elements in order to draw the images on top of the slices in the `addImagesToSlices()` method. Secondly if I try to update the data I still get no smooth transition between the data states. There still is an instant change in the slices on the chart. I am trying to recreate this example into a snippet in order to give you a better look at the example.

Comment: Furthermore I haven't downvoted your answer! I really appreciate the time and effort you put in helping me overcome this problem. I am quite new to this framework and also have a lot to learn off it's inner workings.

Comment: For the previous solution, this is the correct fiddle with the right data key setup https://jsfiddle.net/8xgjz1pv/